# IAMA type questions at stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, questions

being a reddit user, I am wondering if the [IAmA](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/) questions are/would be allowed at stackoverflow, I think they can be fairly useful here.

please let me know what you think.

Comment: Quick information: on Meta, people will downvote to show disagreement, not because your question is badly asked. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Gnoupi Maybe that line should be displayed automatically ;)

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know wtf an IAMA question is? Even after (briefly) glancing at that reddit page? Maybe I'm living in 1995 but I don't even know what reddit is...

Comment: What is a IAmA? I don't want to have to click an external link just in order to understand what you're asking because you can't be bothered typing 4 words....(and in any case, I have blocked reddit.com in my hosts file) ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike [Soylent Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green), these sites are not about people.

I think that questions should be only about particular problems. From what I see, these IAmA questions are more of a discussion type. Not really suitable here, as this is a Q&A site. Ask about a particular problem, get answers. It doesn't matter who is expert or not, the community votes to choose the best answers.

Answer (score 4):

I would say resoundingly **No**, there is already a site with a large user base that has a "ask me anything!" question format in its culture, so those questions should stay on that site.

(I also direct a number of subjective questions and extended discussions to http://reddit.com/r/programming as well, and many SO questions are posted there, so the two sites can happily coexist.)